# Boxcutter slice following the internal contour

Tags: modifiers, boolean-modifier

I would like to know if there is a quick way to use boxcutter slice functionality to get a slice that follows the internal edges of an object. See below:

The below was created in Vanilla -
[image]

Comment: Boxcutter is a third-party addon, not part of Blender so questions about it are off-topic here. However Josh Gambrill has several YT videos using it which include the sort of effect you want so I suggest you look for his videos online.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a dig. Apologies if these questions are not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution without any add-ons if someone looks for it:

1. Select the ominous face(s) of the surface
2. Use "Inset Faces" on them
3. "Bevel" the new edge loop to 3 loops
4. Select the middle loop (by holding ALT) and move it on the appropriate axis or along normals. (You can Bevel them again if you want)

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the effort, I did something similar. Thank you.